# Pasar datos entre ventanas con javafx

Tags: java, formularios, javafx

estoy trabajando con un formulario, el cual tiene varios textFields que quiero llenar tomando el dato desde otra ventana, la ventana de la cual quiero tomar el dato la abro al hacer click sobre un icono que se encuentra ubicado a un costado del textField [image: esta es mi ventana principal]

La segunda ventana la abro al hacer click en el libro que esta del lado izquierdo del textField Proveedor, en la cual solo tengo una tableView y un "buscador"
[image: Esta es la segunda ventana]

desde la cual quiero traerme el nombre del proveedor al hacer click en el registro de la tabla, y que a su vez la segunda ventana se cierre

este es el codigo que tengo al momento de hacer click en el icono:

```
 @FXML
void seleccionarProveedor(MouseEvent event) {
    try {
        Stage proveedores = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)loader.load(getClass().getResource("/interfaces/seleccionarProveedor.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        proveedores.setScene(scene);
        proveedores.alwaysOnTopProperty();
        proveedores.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        proveedores.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InicioController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Y este el que tengo al hacer click en algun registro de la tabla que esta en la segunda ventana:

```
    @FXML
void seleccionarProveedor(MouseEvent event) {
   String nombreProveedor = tblData.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getNombre();
}
```

Es la primera vez que hago una aplicacion con interfaz. Aun no entiendo bien el esqume vista controlador que maneja JavaFx.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas fácil seria usar una variable multiuso del tipo static o serializable. Pudiera ser un List, Hash, map, entre otros que te permita guardar datos de interés sin ningún problema.  La otra seria que al momento de cargar el fxml antes de ser colocado en la scene ubiques los nodos de interes y lo cargues con los datos que necesitas mostrar.

```
 Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));
    // Justo aqui debes hacer el cambio antes de ser mostrado. Recuerda que los nodos de interes deben tener su id. El root contiene los nodos hijos, haz un ciclo iterativo para encontrarlos y luego como son nodos tienes que hacerle un cast
    //ejm; TextField campo = (TextField) nodoEncontrado;

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    stage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo "óptimo" o correcto sería tener un EventBus en tu aplicación. Que la pantalla de selección de la tabla, al seleccionar un proveedor hiciera un EventBus.notifyEvent(Event.SELECTION_PROVIDER, selection.getName()) y tu otra ventana tuviera un EventBus.registerListener(Event.SELECTION_PROVIDER, (String selection) -> { textfield.setText(selection)}.
Todo esto que te pongo es pseudocódigo pero espero que te sirva de guía/ayuda para llegar a una solución. Puedes tener un enum Event con todos los eventos que vayas necesitando. Yo lo utilizo en mis aplicaciones y me resulta muy sencillo la comunicación entre pantallas no relacionadas y es una solución muy limpia.